# How do we create an iOS project with a clean slate (with no Interface Builder files)?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

A book described the following steps for a project without any Interface Builder files:

1. After creating a Single View Application, delete the `.xib` file
2. Find the  `ProjectName-Info.plist` file and remove the `Main nib file base name` property.  (select it and press Delete)
3. Find `main.m` and change the last argument for `UIApplicationMain` to `@"ProjectNameAppDelegate"`
4. remove a `@property` line in `ProjectNameAppDelegate.h` and `@synthesize` in `ProjectNameAppDelegate.m`

I can't find (2) above for the property, and since I am using Xcode 4.3.2, the `ProjectNameAppDelegate.h` has become `AppDelegate.h` (the `.m` as well)... I also see a `window` and `viewController` properties there... and doesn't look like they need to be removed as in step 4.   How can it be done if it is Xcode 4.3.2 (or later?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to create a project with a clean slate, Xcode provides a template called *Empty Application*.

The standard templates don't include a main window nib any more, so the change in #2 is not necessary.  You should make sure you don't enable storyboards when you create your project though.

Yes, the application delegate is just called `AppDelegate` now.  It's just a name.  It doesn't matter.

**Edit:**

Steps to create an iPhone application with a view controller from an empty application template:

1. Create a new project using the *Empty Application* template.
2. Create a new file, pick the *Objective-C class* template.  Make it a subclass of `UIViewController`.
3. Alter `AppDelegate.h` to import your view controller header.
4. Create an instance variable for your application delegate to hold your view controller.
5. Alter `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` to instantiate your view controller, assign it to the instance variable, and add its view as a subview to the window.

Comment: but that one doesn't have a `viewController` either... I think that is wanted, just no `.xib`

Comment: Adding a view controller is very easy and can be done in the app delegate.

Comment: I've added instructions for starting from an empty application template to my answer.

Comment: Can you say what you do to "Create an instance variable for your application delegate to hold your view controller"?  Actually, creating a single view app and removing the `.xib` might be simpler?

Comment: This is very basic Objective-C.  You aren't going to get very far without knowing how to create instance variables.  I suggest you read [Class Implementation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocDefiningClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH12-TPXREF126) in the language reference.

Comment: I know how to create instance variable.  I just don't know what is meant by "an instance variable for your application delegate to hold your view controller"

Comment: What bit are you confused by?  When you tried to create the instance variable, where did you get stuck?

Comment: @Jim I understand more about the creation of UIViewController and UIView more now... don't we have to use `self.window.rootViewController = [[FooViewController alloc] init];` and do we need the instance variable?